# Set server cookie

Tags: python, cookies, header, python-requests

i'm trying to set a cookie for a website, but if I print the cookielist I only get the session ID cookie set by the website and not the one I tried to set.

I tried to follow the documenation but can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Kind regards,
Mark

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.session()
cookie = {"testcookie":"testvalue"}
header = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36)"}
s.get("http://www.example.com", cookies=cookie, headers=header)

# Get xsrf code
loginpage = s.get("https://example.com/login/", headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(loginpage.text)
xsrflist = []
source=soup.findAll('input',{"value":True})
for sources in source:
    print (sources['value'])
    xsrflist.append(sources["value"])
xsrf = xsrflist[0]

# Login
payload = {"username" : "usernamel", "password" : "password1", 'anti_xsrf_token' : xsrf}
login = s.post("https://example.com/login/", data=payload, cookies=cookie, headers=header)

print(s.headers)
print (requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(s.cookies))
```

Comment: you can use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/)  so you dont need to maintain the sessions and then do what want to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you elaborate on this? I am aware of selenium but in this specific case what improvement does selenium offer over requests?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set a server cookie. When you send cookies to the server, the server can do anything, including ignoring, with them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this makes it more clear. So I should never have to send  the server a cookie because the purpose of the cookie is the info.   So if for example there is a session ID in the cookie, I should find where the Session ID is being requested and use that instead of trying to use the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

To install selenium

```
pip install selenium
```

Here is the solution.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('yoururl')
htmlpage = driver.page_source
#do something with htmlpage
```